# Deploy Python app with textract module to Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I want to create a Python script that will parse 40.000 PDF files(text and images). Since I saw that there is no easy method to check if a page contains images I think I should use textract module.

Ideally I would deploy to Google App Engine.

My question is, for textract I've also installed other packages beside Python to my system. Can I deploy the script(with  proper requirements.txt file) on Google Cloud App Engine without problem? or I will to use something else?

Comment: Google app engine is commonly used to service incoming REST requests.  What is your high level architecture?   My immediate gut feel would be to load the 40K PDFs into Google Cloud storage and then use a Compute Engine hosted application to process these.  By using Compute Engine, you have full control over the characteristics of the machine (CPUs, memory etc etc).  I'd also be tempted to look into horizontal scaling ... you could create a group of Compute Engines and have these excuted in parallel.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it this way. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use App Engine, but only with the [Flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/) and using a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes), which allows you to add non-python dependencies (and also python dependencies not installable via `pip`):

> Custom runtimes allow you to define new runtime environments, which
>   might include additional components like language interpreters or
>   application servers.

See also [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build).

Comment: Thank you very much. What would you choose though ?

Comment: Personally I prefer PaaS to IaaS (kinda against the current) so I'd definitely give GAE a try 1st. Only if the estimate based on that trial would prove way too costly I'd maybe consider IaaS.