# Deploying Custom Python packages in GAE which are not available under pip

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am facing some issue with deploying a custom package (to be more specific `2checkout` https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-python ) in a Django Project via Google App Engine.

As in order to deploy, we do need a file `requirements.txt` to be included with the python package dependencies (which can be installed via pip), but in the case of a custom package (like the above mentioned), how can we implement the custom package in Google App Engine.

Comment: What environment/runtime are you using?

Comment: I use 3.7 @Dan Cornilescu

Comment: standard or flexible env?

Comment: Any, but the currently deployed app is in standard, but I can change it to flexible. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the standard environment you can install the package into your application locally so that it's deployed as part of your app. From [Private dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#private_dependencies):

> Dependencies are installed in a Cloud Build environment that does not
>   provide access to SSH keys. Packages hosted on repositories that
>   require SSH-based authentication must be copied into your project
>   directory and uploaded alongside your project's code using the
>   [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip) package manager.
>
> To use private dependencies:
>
> Run `pip install -t lib my_module` to copy dependencies into a local
>   folder named `lib`.
>
> Add an empty `__init__.py` file to the `lib` directory to make it a
>   module.
>
> Import the module in your app. For example:
>
> ```
> import lib.my_module
> ```

If you're using the flexible environment you can build a [custom runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes), see [Deploy Python app with textract module to Google Cloud Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56210862/deploy-python-app-with-textract-module-to-google-cloud-platform/56222595#56222595).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Dan! I'll check this out.